# cv2.rectangle not working when using a tuple from a np array as color

Tags: python, opencv

I was trying to make rectangles with random colors in a script, but I came across this really weird bug where, when I use a hard-coded color everything works fine (like (255, 0, 0)), but when I try to make a random color using np.random.randint, it gives me the following error:

> TypeError: function takes exactly 4 arguments (2 given)

This minimal code reproduces my problem.

```
import numpy as np
from cv2 import cv2
    
img = np.ones((900, 1200), dtype='uint8')
color = tuple(np.random.randint(0, 256, 3, dtype='uint8')) # Does not work
color = (127, 127, 127) # Works
cv2.rectangle(img, (100, 100), (300, 300), color, 4)
```

Comment: If anyone come across this problem, one workaround I just found was using the method .tolist() from the np array, and after converting the list to a tuple. But still it bothers me why the direct conversion does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution: call the `.tolist()` method on the numpy array, then convert the list to a tuple using `tuple()`.

What's going on:

OpenCV expects not just a tuple, but a tuple of *Python* integers.

Simply calling `tuple()` on anything iterable (lists, numpy arrays, ...) puts those elements, as they are, into the tuple. `tuple()` iterates over whatever you pass in. It could even be an object of a class you wrote, if you implement the required methods to make it an [iterable](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterable). Guess what `tuple("foo")` does? It does `('f', 'o', 'o')`

In the case of a numpy array, its elements are instances of numpy number types. From simply `print`ing such an element, you can't tell the difference.

Observe:

```py
>>> numbers = np.random.randint(0, 256, 3, dtype='uint8')
>>> numbers # it's a numpy ndarray
array([243, 188, 231], dtype=uint8)
>>> numbers[0] # looks like a regular Python integer?
243
>>> type(numbers[0]) # it's not a regular Python integer
<class 'numpy.uint8'>
>>> type(tuple(numbers)[0]) # even "converting" to a tuple doesn't fix it
<class 'numpy.uint8'>
```

And this is what needs to happen for OpenCV to be happy:

```py
>>> numbers.tolist() # this is not enough for OpenCV
[243, 188, 231]
>>> type(_[0]) # type of elements is correct at least
<class 'int'>
>>> tuple(numbers.tolist()) # OpenCV wants this
(243, 188, 231)
```

NB: This is a common issue with OpenCV when it wants tuples of integers... e.g. when you try to pass in a point (for the corners of the rectangle) and the point happens to consist of floating point numbers. In that case, OpenCV doesn't like floats regardless of whether they're Python or numpy. It wants integers there. That behavior may change in the future, I hope.

Answer (score 3):

It's odd behavior indeed, but the following will work in your case:

Edit: Christoph's comment is correct. You simply need to call `tolist()` to convert the color to a python scalar.

**Example:**

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

img = np.ones((900, 1200), dtype='uint8')
color = np.random.randint(0, 256, 3, dtype=np.uint8)

cv2.rectangle(img, (100, 100), (300, 300), color.tolist(), 4)

cv2.imshow("Test", img)
cv2.waitKey()
```

**Output:**

[image: output jpg]

Comment: Thank you! Didn't know you could directly use a list

Comment: You're 100% correct in pointing out that it's a strange bug with OpenCV and Python. Even positional arguments won't work. For whatever reason, the function signature in the C-bindings don't line up correctly.

Comment: that explanation is wrong. the issue here is that the tuple contains elements of type `numpy.uint8`, when OpenCV requires the tuple's elements to be of python's `int` type. `.tolist()` converts numpy scalar types to python scalar types (int, float)

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Thanks. Updated the answer. You're correct. I was noticing some strange behavior with the `rec` positional argument when I was fiddling around with the problem. So, I blindly assumed it was a binding issue.